# Contact form with ajax. How to write path to "mail.php" (im using gulp)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, gulp

Im trying to make contact form with ajax. The files index.html, mail.php are in the same folder.
When I click on Submit button, nothing happens. Console says "POST http://localhost:3000/mail.php 404 error". If I go to http://localhost:3000/mail.php, the file is downloaded. 
I cant understand why it doesnt work with ajax contact form.

I tried to copy all the files to another folder (without gulp files) and it worked. But how to make it work with gulp?

index.html

```
<form id="form">
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Ваше имя" required /><br />
        <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Ваш телефон" required /><br />
        <button>Submit</button>
    </form>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>


    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#form").submit(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/mail.php",
                data: $(this).serialize()
            }).done(function() {
                $(this).find("input").val("");
                alert("Спасибо за заявку! Скоро мы с вами свяжемся.");
                $("#form").trigger("reset");
            });
            return false;
        });

    });</script>
```

mail.php

```
?php

$recepient = "...@gmail.com";
$sitename = "Название сайта";

$name = trim($_POST["name"]);
$phone = trim($_POST["phone"]);
$text = trim($_POST["text"]);
$message = "Имя: $name \nТелефон: $phone \nТекст: $text";

$pagetitle = "Новая заявка с сайта \"$sitename\"";
mail($recepient, $pagetitle, $message, "Content-type: text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\"\n From: $recepient");
```

I feel quite confused. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Can you share your php file as well?

Comment: I added php file as well.

Comment: When you tried to serve the files without gulp, which web server did you use?
gulp serves the client side, you need web server for the php as well

Comment: I use OpenServer and it works great. So i need to install something in gulp?

Comment: well you need to start a php server in order to use php, if you wish to use gulp

try using gulp-connect-php

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-connect-php

Comment: Thanks! I installed it but i have the same problem. It works well only if I open it with OpenServer. It doesnt work in http://localhost:3000, though if i go to http://localhost:3000/mail.php it will download the file.

Comment: I suggest you to have a web server app that will serve both client&backend like xampp/wammp for windows, or apache2 for linux

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var baseUrl = window.location.host;

    $("#form").submit(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: baseUrl+"/mail.php",
            data: $(this).serialize()
        }).done(function() {
            $(this).find("input").val("");
            alert("Спасибо за заявку! Скоро мы с вами свяжемся.");
            $("#form").trigger("reset");
        });
        return false;
    });

});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Masud! I tried your code and it didnt make correct path. Though I tried to open website with OpenServer instead of using gulp and my previous code worked.  
I dont know what is wrong with Gulp..